# View organic traffic from all domains simultaneously

Tags: google-analytics

I like the home-view of Analytics, since it let's me get a traffic overview of all 45 domains I'm managing inside Analytics. I have been wondering for a long time if it would be somehow possible to have a similar list of all my domains, but the metric I would like to see would be only organic search traffic.

In other words: Is it somehow possible to list the organic search traffic amounts of all domains on a single page, or do I always have to dig into each site individually to see this metric?

Comment: As Sam Perry points out, the API is what you need to get the data.  But if you are looking for a solution which doesn't require you to dig into the API, check out http://www.embeddedanalytics.com. (I created the service).  I have seen some of our users do exactly this.  One page in particular shows charts for about 60 profiles.  Contact us if you need assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) is perfect for this. I would recommend creating a dashboard with the API to pull in hostname, sessions and filter by Organic traffic. This can be done with your favourite programming language or it's easy to use [Google Sheets with the API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/reporting-apps-script).